# Beautiful Soup fails to recognize UTF-8 encoding on Python 3, IPython 6 console

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, utf-8, beautifulsoup

I am trying to read an xml document using Beautiful Soup on Python 3.6.2, IPython 6.1.0, Windows 10, and I can't get the encoding right.

Here's my test xml, saved as a file in UTF8-encoding:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<info name="愛よ">ÜÜÜÜÜÜÜ</info>
<items>
<item thing="ÖöÖö">"23Äßßß"</item>
</items>
</root>
```

First check the XML using ElementTree:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def printXML(xml,indent=''):
    print(indent+str(xml.tag)+': '+(xml.text if xml.text is not None else '').replace('\n',''))
    if len(xml.attrib) > 0:
        for k,v in xml.attrib.items():
            print(indent+'\t'+k+' - '+v)
    if xml.getchildren():
        for child in xml.getchildren():
            printXML(child,indent+'\t')

xml0 = ET.parse("test.xml").getroot()
printXML(xml0)
```

The output is correct:

```
root: 
        info: ÜÜÜÜÜÜÜ
                name - 愛よ
        items: 
                item: "23Äßßß"
                        thing - ÖöÖö
```

Now read the same file with Beautiful Soup and pretty-print it:

```
import bs4

with open("test.xml") as ff:
    xml = bs4.BeautifulSoup(ff,"html5lib")
print(xml.prettify())
```

Output:

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?-->
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <root>
   <info name="æ„›ã‚ˆ">
    ÃœÃœÃœÃœÃœÃœÃœ
   </info>
   <items>
    <item thing="Ã–Ã¶Ã–Ã¶">
     "23Ã„ÃŸÃŸÃŸ"
    </item>
   </items>
  </root>
 </body>
</html>
```

This is just wrong. Doing the call with explicite encoding specified `bs4.BeautifulSoup(ff,"html5lib",from_encoding="UTF-8")` doesn't change the result.

Doing

```
print(xml.original_encoding)
```

outputs

```
None
```

So Beautiful Soup is apparently unable to detect the original encoding even though the file is encoded in UTF8 (according to Notepad++) and the header information says UTF-8 as well, and I do have `chardet` installed [as the doc recommends](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#unicode-dammit).

Am I making a mistake here? What could be causing this?

EDIT:
When I invoke the code without the `html5lib` I get this warning:

```
UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("html5lib"). 
This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, 
it may use a different parser and behave differently.

The code that caused this warning is on line 241 of the file C:\Users\My.Name\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\Python3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py. 
To get rid of this warning, change code that looks like this:

 BeautifulSoup(YOUR_MARKUP})

to this:

 BeautifulSoup(YOUR_MARKUP, "html5lib")

  markup_type=markup_type))
```

EDIT 2:

As suggested in a comment I tried `bs4.BeautifulSoup(ff,"html.parser")`, but the problem remains.

Then I installed `lxml` and tried `bs4.BeautifulSoup(ff,"lxml-xml")`, still the same output.

What also strikes me as odd is that even when specifying an encoding like `bs4.BeautifulSoup(ff,"lxml-xml",from_encoding='UTF-8')` the value of `xml.original_encoding` is `None` contrary to what is [written in the doc](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#encodings).

EDIT 3:

I put my xml contents into a string

```
xmlstring = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><root><info name=\"愛よ\">ÜÜÜÜÜÜÜ</info><items><item thing=\"ÖöÖö\">\"23Äßßß\"</item></items></root>"
```

And used `bs4.BeautifulSoup(xmlstring,"lxml-xml")`, now I'm getting the correct output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
 <info name="愛よ">
  ÜÜÜÜÜÜÜ
 </info>
 <items>
  <item thing="ÖöÖö">
   "23Äßßß"
  </item>
 </items>
</root>
```

So it seems something is wrong with the file after all.

Comment: Why are you trying to process an xml file using an html5 parser? Look at the first line of the bs4 output - can you see the problem this has caused?

Comment: This is not an HTML5 document, that's probably why it failed to decode to what you expected.

Comment: Because when executing the code without that I get this: `UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("html5lib").` (Adding that part to the Question now.)

Comment: Do I have to install `lxml`?

Comment: Hmm, this is does not look like a Python problem on Windows10, because I cannot reproduce on  my Python 3.6.2, parsing with `"html.parser"`, because `html5lib` is not available. You could try to use same parser I use, and if it still gives weird result then the problem is in your IPython installation.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Thanks for the comment, I'm getting the same problem with that parser.

Answer (score 4):

Found the error, I have to specify the encoding when opening the file:

```
with open("test.xml",encoding='UTF-8') as ff:
    xml = bs4.BeautifulSoup(ff,"html5lib")
```

As I'm on Python 3 I thought the value of `encoding` was `UTF-8` by default, but it turned out it's system-dependent and on my system it's `cp1252`.

Comment: This was helpful to me. I want to do `responseObject = requests.get(someUrl)` and then `soup = BeautifulSoup(responseObject.text, "html.parser")`. It seems to be necessary to fix the encoding by inserting `responseObject.encoding = responseObject.apparent_encoding` (or `= "utf-8"`) between these two lines. Trying to fix the encoding after creating `soup` does not work. Like Khris I am using Windows 10 and Python 3.6.